# NodeJS jQuery ".find" method can't parse the elements contain "&nbsp;"

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, find, selector

While i use `$(something).find()` in NODEJS, it got errors when the content contains `&nbsp;` inside. Errors like:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: &nbsp;
    at Function.error (/project_path/jquery.min.js:3:15266)
```

- It works properly for the contents which `NOT` includes `&nbsp;` inside. Weird!
- How can i make it work? :(

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly use Jquery by putting jquery javascript file in your node project and using it in your code. As there is no DOM in node.js (as it is basically server app).

You have to install jquery on server by:

```
npm install jquery
```

it installs node-jquery: https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery,
with dependencies jsdom: https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom and htmlparser: https://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser.

Basically these dependencies will create fake DOM for jquery to work with.
Ideally you should not require jquery on server.

Comment: Did i ask about jQuery installation problem in Node.js??? And what then? So can you use `.find() method` in Node.js jQuery after you installed like that? For the elements that contain `&nbsp;` characters inside.

Comment: Wow... this person tries to help and you respond with some entitled remark?

Comment: @4lvin, Easy mate. Error at "/project_path/jquery.min.js:3:15266" clearly explains that you have added jquery js directly, you are not using node compatible jquery code. And yes it should allow you to use .find() method.

Comment: The issue here is just: `why` is it, the `.find()` method working for the any all other elements which NOT contains `&nbsp;` charactor inside? Also, all of other `jQuery` functionalities are working properly well.

Comment: can you try what I have suggested? Cause one of your question is "How can i make it work? :(" And, what I have suggested should solve this problem.